# Test the execution of a Selenium automation

Tags: selenium, browser-automation

I don't know if this is unusual, but I'm wondering if I should test my automation that uses Selenium (written in Python).

Basically, I have to login and perform some actions in an old web application that doesn't have public APIs, so this is the only way to automate what I need to do. It's an application from my city hall to create tax receipts.

But I couldn't think of a way to test if my code will work. Right now it's working, but I'm refactoring a few things and thought that there could be something I can do to test if things will continue to work as they should. The problem is that it's a critical automation, and it's only used once per month; I don't have access to any kind of sandbox environment. What I usually do if I need to run the automation is to create a tax receipt of my own company, with $1 value, and then I just cancel it, but it's... weird.

One thing that crossed my mind was to perform the automation one time and in every step just save the whole HTML. Then, I could write tests and mock the page clicks / navigation; instead of loading the URL, it would load the HTML file.

I know it wont't be 100%, in production there can be errors that I haven't foreseen. But then I can update my tests to include these corner cases as they happen. Anyone had experience with this type of thing before?

Comment: Seems like you need to create your own sandbox to test properly... and without endangering sensitive data.   Any way to host your own mirror of the site on localhost?

Comment: but then should you write tests for the tests that test the tests? :)

Comment: @pcalkins probably yes, but I have to deal with iframes... there is the main page/HTML with a placeholder div, and when I select one option from the menu, some javascript loads an iframe with the response in this div. ancient stuff! I don't even know how to setup navigation in this case... but thanks, it seems like a better approach!

Comment: You'd just switch the driver to the frame.... usually it'll have an id or name you can use for that.  To switch back, you can switch to window[0].

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg well... it's kind of an Inception thing. I know SO isn't the best place to ask this kind of question, because the answer can be sort of opinion based. I'm just curious if anyone had this type of problem before, and if it's better to just log a bunch of stuff (I'm already doing that) in case of production errors, or to create tests. Google didn't help, in every search I only got tutorials to automate tests with Selenium, and not test an automation that's performing an action in a system I don't own!

Comment: @pcalkins Yes, my code does that! I was thinking about the sandbox setup, I never did anything with <iframe> tags. In my first idea, I would just save a lot of HTML files (one for each iframe I need), and mock the calls to driver.switch_to.frame('ID'); instead, I'd load the HTML in the driver. But I'm thinking it's better to build a sandbox if I decide to test this stuff :)

Comment: If it's an application, saving the HTML files won't work.  You'll only get the view... and there would be nothing to process data.  To properly test something you need to test it as close to a real-world situation as possible.  Which is why Selenium is so good for testing web apps.  Testing live sites is the best case... if you must sandbox, keep the number of changed variables as small as possible.

Comment: btw, there are some tools I used to use a very long time ago that would do just what you are saying.  You just point it to a URL and it'll automatically go through the links and return static pages for everything.  You might want to just google "free website downloader".  While it's not the best test case, it's better than nothing I suppose.  Depending on what you are trying to test it might help though it may change certain links.